# cts search to test if the element is not available

Tags: xquery, marklogic, cts

Below is the XML structure where I want to get the entries for which element co:isbn is not available:-

```
<tr:trackingRecord xmlns:tr="https://www.mla.org/Schema/Tracking/tr"
    xmlns:co="https://www.mla.org/Schema/commonModule/co"
    xmlns:r="http://www.rsuitecms.com/rsuite/ns/metadata">
    <tr:journal>
        <tr:trackingDetails>
            <tr:entry>
                <co:trackingEntryID>2015323313</co:trackingEntryID>
                <co:publicationDate>2015</co:publicationDate>
                <co:volume>21</co:volume>
            </tr:entry>
            <tr:entry>
                <co:trackingEntryID>2015323314</co:trackingEntryID>
                <co:publicationDate>2015</co:publicationDate>
                <co:isbn>
                    <co:entry>NA</co:entry>
                    <co:value>1234567890128</co:value>
                </co:isbn>
            </tr:entry>
            <tr:entry>
                <co:trackingEntryID>2015323315</co:trackingEntryID>
                <co:publicationDate>2015</co:publicationDate>
                <co:volume>21</co:volume>
                <co:isbn></co:isbn>
            </tr:entry>
            <tr:entry>
                <co:trackingEntryID>2015323316</co:trackingEntryID>
                <co:publicationDate>2015</co:publicationDate>
                <co:volume>21</co:volume>
            </tr:entry>
        </tr:trackingDetails>
    </tr:journal>
</tr:trackingRecord>
```

Please suggest the cts:query for the same.

Comment: Looks like a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251178/search-xmls-which-do-not-have-particular-element-in-marklogic

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit xml structure, add one attribute in entry element, like

```
<tr:entry isbnPresent="yes"> for isbn present,
<tr:entry isbnPresent="no"> for isbn absent
```

and based on these field fire search with,

```
cts:element-attribute-value
```

on it.

OR

without editing schema, try like, ,

```
for $i in cts:search(//tr:entry,"2015")
return if(fn:exists($i//co:isbn)) then () else $i
```

Comment: Adding attribute required schema changes as well. That we don't want to do.

Without changing the XML structure can we do something?

Comment: check fn:exists  with iterator as given above, given it may slow down the operations for huge files