# MarkLogic: Find documents where at least one parent element does not have a particular child

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10, marklogic-dhf

Using the built-in MarkLogic cts functions, I'd like to be able to write a query which can find a document like the following -- where exists at least 1  element that does not have a `<child1>` element (`parents/parent[2]`). BUT I do not want to exclude documents which have the `<child1>` element (`parents/parent[1]` or `parents/parent[3]`) from the search results.

```
<doc>
   <root>
      <parents>
         <parent>
            <child1>someValue</child1>
            <child2>someValue</child2>
         </parent>
         <parent>
            <child2>someValue</child2>
         </parent>
         <parent>
            <child1>someValue</child1>
            <child2>someValue</child2>
         </parent>
      </parents>
   </root>
</doc>
```

My thought process was that simply negating the following would return what I'm searching for:

Positive xQuery:

```
let $query :=
cts:element-query(
   xs:QName('parent')
   ,cts:element-query(
      xs:QName('child1')
      ,cts:true-query()
      )
   )
return cts:search(fn:doc(),$query)
```

or using the search module:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

let $options := 
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
        
  <extract-document-data selected="include">
    <extract-path xmlns:es="http://marklogic.com/entity-services">//root</extract-path>
  </extract-document-data>

  <additional-query>
      <cts:element-query>
        <cts:element>parent</cts:element>
          <cts:element-query>
            <cts:element>child1</cts:element>
            <cts:true-query>
            </cts:true-query>
        </cts:element-query>
      </cts:element-query>
  </additional-query>
  
</options>
return search:search("",$options)
```

Leading to my attempted query:

Negative xQuery:

```
let $query :=
cts:not-query(
   cts:element-query(
      XS:QName('parent')
      ,cts:element-query(
         XS:QName('child1')
         ,cts:true-query()
         )
      )
   )
return cts:search(fn:doc(),$query)
```

Upon further evaluation though, it's clear why the "Negative" query does not evaluate as I'd expect...The positive query returns documents where the path `//parent/child1` exists... the opposite of this is "return documents where `//parent/child1` does not exist"...

Nonetheless, I am perplexed how to do this in an efficient way utilizing MarkLogic's cts functions. This database harvests billions of documents, vanilla xquery/xpath will be time consuming. I'm really hoping to achieve this using the search module/api -- Please keep in mind (despite my search module example above) that to run this query I'm hoping to make it via an api call to the search REST endpoint, so I will not be able to enhance the server side search with xQuery. Although if it can only be achieved using pure xQuery, it is what it is and I can just use the eval REST endpoint.

While looking for information I did come across this similar post from 6 years ago:
[search-xmls-which-do-not-have-particular-element-in-marklogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251178/search-xmls-which-do-not-have-particular-element-in-marklogic)

But it has been a fair amount of time since that was asked, its tagged for marklogic-8, and my question differs to a good degree since I'm hoping to achieve this with the out of the box search module/api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found an answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73504631/2292130

With the element position index enabled, you should be able to use [cts:not-in-query](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:not-in-query). Rule in all the hits for `parent`, and then rule out all the hits for `parent/child1`.

```
cts:not-in-query(
  cts:element-query(xs:QName('parent'), cts:true-query()),
  cts:element-query(xs:QName('parent'),
    cts:element-query(xs:QName('child1'), cts:true-query())
  )
)
```

This works because unlike, e.g. `cts:and-not-query`, the position of the matches in the document is taken into account before returning results.

> Returns a query matching the first sub-query, *where those matches do not occur within 0 distance of the other query*.

Your example document will have three matches for the positive query (that is to say, `parent` nodes), and two hits for the negative query (`child1` nodes in `parent` nodes). But those two negative-query matches are at the same position (0 positions removed from) two of the positive-query matches. Those two overlaps get excluded, but the document has one positive match remaining, which therefore counts as a match for the `cts:not-in-query` as a whole.

Comment: Thank you! I did come across this function in my search — but assumed it would grab all documents containing `parent` (positive query) and then exclude all of the documents containing `parent/child1`?  So the document in my example would be excluded…. Can you help me understand what I’m missing?

Comment: I updated the answer with some more detail. Hope that helps!

Comment: Sincerely, thank you so much for your help and your explanation! I did not initially understand what the documentation meant by occurring within 0 distance from the other query. Your clarification was excellent! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the `cts` functions in Marklogic, but the following XQuery condition tests whether a document satisfies your criteria

```
where some $p in $doc//parent satisfies empty($p/child1)
```

or more concisely

```
where $doc//parent[not(child1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Additionally, thank you for teaching me everything I know about XSLT -- your books are great lol.